# Why is the lifespan of variables exported in .bashrc and .profile different?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, profile

If a variable is exported from .profile, it is present in all the terminals I open after log in, even though the variable was exported only once at the log in time.
If a variable is exported from .bashrc (it gets sourced every single time I open a new terminal) I can use it, but if removing the variable export from .bashrc and then opening a new terminal the variable is no more present.
So why are the variables exported from .profile, that is read once at the log in, permanent, and the ones exported from .bashrc not?

In my understanding exporting through .bashrc is like manually typing it in every terminal session. Is exporting through .profile actually remembering the variables the entire log in session or what does it actually happen, so the variables get permanent?

Comment: I'm guessing there is a login shell reading your `.profile` and then starting your graphical interface. Any software started from that single login shell would inherit all environment variables (i.e. the exported shell variables), including terminals etc. It's unclear whether this is a question about how environment variables work, or whether it's about the role of the shell's various startup files, or whether it's about the difference between a login shell and an interactive non-login shell, or whether it's about the specific steps your GUI takes when initiating the environment.

Comment: @they sorry if the question may seem that confuse, because so I am. I was assuming that there could be a parent shell from which the terminals where inheriting, but again for me it's like something completely new. Thanks a lot for your response. Your comment did actually answer my question.